# Ionic V1 tabs + SQLite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

friends.

I have ionic V1 application with 2 tabs, add and list. And for persist the data, I use SQLite.

My problem.

In add tab, I insert data in database perfectly, but, when I redirect to list, the last that i insert, doesn't display on list

```
arrList = []
db.transaction(function (tx) 
{
    var query_users = "SELECT * FROM users";
    tx.executeSql(query_users, [], function (tx, results) 
    {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arrList.push(results.rows[i]);
        }
    }, null);
});
$scope.userList = arrList;
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                   {
        $scope.arrList.push({id: result.rows.item(i).id, message: 
         result.rows.item(i).message});

                   }
```

i  used to push data in this way..
ie is... result.rows.item(i).["variable name"]
may be it will help u...